# Fast way to get AWS S3 key count in bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Is there anyone out there knowing a fast way to get the count of my keys in S3?

I usually do `s3cmd ls s3://bucket/ | wc -l` but my bucket contains a huge number of keys which makes this operation impossible to finish.

Comment: I think that list bucket is the only way to do that.

Comment: don't they keep any internal stats?? they should..

Comment: Maybe usage report provides that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to count the bucket object using aws s3 api -

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucketNameToUse --query '[length(Contents[?LastModified].{Key: Key})]' --output text
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super old question, but I figured I'd add my $.02.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $YOUR_BUCKET --no-cli-pager --query "Contents[].Key" --output text | wc -w
```

This will give you a count thats pretty close and works better for me that Vipin's answer

Comment: Is this significantly different from doing `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`? Seems maybe the same-ish?